# Animate an icon from the contentView to the navigation bar during the scroll

Tags: ios, ios8

I got a task from the designer that seemed to require some kind of hack to be accomplished.
Basically I have to animate the face icon to the top of the navigation bar while the content is scrolled up.

Is there a way to do that? Is there an elegant way?

[image: Icon transition]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to do that? Yes

Elegant? Eh... it's going to be a good amount of work to make it elegant, perhaps enough to justify a conversation with your designer on whether or not another effect might be a better use of time.

But to your question... first you will need to provide more clarity on how the animation is to function. Does the face stay in the center of the top cell until it hits some threshold and then animates to the nav bar in one go? Or does the animation respond as a direct and smooth function of scrolling (animating closer or further further from the nav bar as the user scrolls)? The former is probably easier to code, but it sounds like you want the latter. IMO the latter is less ideal because the interface can wind up in undesired states (e.g. the face floating halfway between the cell and the nav bar).

Comment: The second option is indeed what I need.This intermediate state is also desired

Comment: I have to lodge my complaint that I think it's not a good design choice to leave a picture floating around in an arbitrary location based off of scroll position. You might want to find an easier way to mock this up (even using paper mock ups) and check with your designer that how it looks is what is intended. Perhaps ask for an example of an app or webpage that has the effect they are looking for just to make sure you are on the same page. Sorry to triple check, but before I spend time outlining how I would execute a design that I don't agree with, I just want to make sure it's what you want.